# WPF Inner Glow Effect

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0

Does anyone know how to make an Inner Glow effect in WPF **without** using expression blend or deprecated BitmapEffects?

Sample image:

[image]

For instance, here is some xaml for a button with an image and some text. I want this button to have an inner glow (not an outer glow):

```
<Button Click="HandleDeleteRows" Style="{StaticResource ButtonCellStyle}">
    <DockPanel>
        <Image Style="{StaticResource DeleteButtonImage}" />
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource DeleteButtonCaption}" />
    </DockPanel>
</Button>
```

Comment: Is there perhaps a way I can define my own Effect class to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While my simplified example above is solved by PompolutZ's answer, I wasn't in a position to override the control template of the control I wanted to apply the style to in my real world example - so I took to defining my own Effect, following instructions [here](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-35sp1-more-effects.aspx).

**Step 1** - Write an HLSL .FX file that will do your desired effect. I gave up on the glow as being too complicated, since it required edge detection. I decided to go with a slew of standard colour, brightness, gamma, and saturation adjustments that were fairly easy to implement and would let me create some good visual cues. They were pretty easy to implement using common sense and looking up pixel shading algorithms online.

`ColourAdjust.fx`:

```
sampler2D implicitInput : register(s0);
float saturation : register(c0);
float gamma : register(c1);
float brightness : register(c2);
float red_adjust : register(c3);
float green_adjust : register(c4);
float blue_adjust : register(c5);

static const float max_gamma = 100;

float4 main(float2 uv : TEXCOORD) : COLOR
{
    float4 color = tex2D(implicitInput, uv);
    float4 result;

    // Apply greyscale desaturation
    float gray = color.r * 0.3 + color.g * 0.59 + color.b *0.11; 
    result.r = (color.r - gray) * saturation + gray;
    result.g = (color.g - gray) * saturation + gray;
    result.b = (color.b - gray) * saturation + gray;

    // Apply Gamma Adjustment (if it's not approximately 0.5 - which means no adjustment)
    float gammafactor = gamma == 0 ? max_gamma : log(gamma) / log(0.5);
    result.r = pow(result.r, gammafactor);
    result.g = pow(result.g, gammafactor);
    result.b = pow(result.b, gammafactor);

    //Apply linear brightness adjustment
    result.r += brightness + red_adjust;
    result.g += brightness + green_adjust;
    result.b += brightness + blue_adjust;

    //Clamp brightness adjustment result to bounds 0 <= val <= 1
    result.r = (result.r > 1 ? 1 : (result.r < 0 ? 0 : result.r));
    result.g = (result.g > 1 ? 1 : (result.g < 0 ? 0 : result.g));
    result.b = (result.b > 1 ? 1 : (result.b < 0 ? 0 : result.b));

    result.a = color.a;
    return result;
}
```

**Step 2** - I had to download a local copy of the [DirectX SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139765.aspx) so that I could compile the above HLSL code into a PS file, which is what's used by WPF - giving me `ColourAdjust.ps`.

```
> > fxc.exe /T ps_2_0 /E PS /ColourAdjust.ps ColourAdjust.fx
```

**Step 3** - Write a ShaderEffect class that will expose the effect parameters via DependencyProperties. Here is `ColourAdjustEffect.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Effects;

namespace WPF.Utilities.UI
{
    public class ColourAdjustEffect : ShaderEffect
    {
        private static PixelShader _pixelShader = new PixelShader() { UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/" + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() + ";component/Effects/ColourAdjust.ps") };
        public static readonly DependencyProperty InputProperty = ShaderEffect.RegisterPixelShaderSamplerProperty("Input", typeof(ColourAdjustEffect), 0);
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SaturationProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Saturation", typeof(double), typeof(ColourAdjustEffect), new UIPropertyMetadata(1.0, PixelShaderConstantCallback(0), CoerceFactor));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty GammaProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Gamma", typeof(double), typeof(ColourAdjustEffect), new UIPropertyMetadata(0.5, PixelShaderConstantCallback(1), CoerceFactor));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty BrightnessAdjustmentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BrightnessAdjustment", typeof(double), typeof(ColourAdjustEffect), new UIPropertyMetadata(0.0, PixelShaderConstantCallback(2), CoerceBrightnessAdjustment));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty RedAdjustmentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("RedAdjustment", typeof(double), typeof(ColourAdjustEffect), new UIPropertyMetadata(0.0, PixelShaderConstantCallback(3), CoerceBrightnessAdjustment));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty GreenAdjustmentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("GreenAdjustment", typeof(double), typeof(ColourAdjustEffect), new UIPropertyMetadata(0.0, PixelShaderConstantCallback(4), CoerceBrightnessAdjustment));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty BlueAdjustmentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BlueAdjustment", typeof(double), typeof(ColourAdjustEffect), new UIPropertyMetadata(0.0, PixelShaderConstantCallback(5), CoerceBrightnessAdjustment));

        public ColourAdjustEffect()
        {
            PixelShader = _pixelShader;

            UpdateShaderValue(InputProperty);
            UpdateShaderValue(SaturationProperty);
            UpdateShaderValue(GammaProperty);
            UpdateShaderValue(BrightnessAdjustmentProperty);
            UpdateShaderValue(RedAdjustmentProperty);
            UpdateShaderValue(GreenAdjustmentProperty);
            UpdateShaderValue(BlueAdjustmentProperty);
        }

        public Brush Input
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(InputProperty); }
            set { SetValue(InputProperty, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>A value between 0 and 1 to alter the amount of colour left in the image. 0 is entirely greyscale, and 1 is unaffected. Default is 1.</summary>
        public double Saturation
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(SaturationProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SaturationProperty, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>A value between 0 and 1 to alter the lightness of the greyscale without altering true black or true white. 
        /// 0 shifts shades closer to true black, and 1 shifts shades closer to true white. Default is 0.5.</summary>
        public double Gamma
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(GammaProperty); }
            set { SetValue(GammaProperty, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>A value between -1 and 1 to linearly move the end result closer to true black or true white respectively.
        /// -1 will result in an entirely black image, +1 will result in an entirely white image. Default is 0.</summary>
        public double BrightnessAdjustment
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(BrightnessAdjustmentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BrightnessAdjustmentProperty, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>A value between -1 and 1 to linearly increase the Red component of the result.
        /// -1 will remove all Red from the image, +1 will maximize all Red in the image. Default is 0.</summary>
        public double RedAdjustment
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(RedAdjustmentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(RedAdjustmentProperty, value); }
        }
        /// <summary>A value between -1 and 1 to linearly increase the Green component of the result.
        /// -1 will remove all Green from the image, +1 will maximize all Green in the image. Default is 0.</summary>
        public double GreenAdjustment
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(GreenAdjustmentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(GreenAdjustmentProperty, value); }
        }
        /// <summary>A value between -1 and 1 to linearly increase the Blue component of the result.
        /// -1 will remove all Blue from the image, +1 will maximize all Blue in the image. Default is 0.</summary>
        public double BlueAdjustment
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(BlueAdjustmentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BlueAdjustmentProperty, value); }
        }

        private static object CoerceFactor(DependencyObject d, object value)
        {
            double newFactor = (double)value;

            if( newFactor < 0.0 ) return 0.0;
            if( newFactor > 1.0 ) return 1.0;
            return newFactor;
        }

        private static object CoerceBrightnessAdjustment(DependencyObject d, object value)
        {
            double newFactor = (double)value;

            if( newFactor < -1.0 ) return -1.0;
            if( newFactor > 1.0 ) return 1.0;
            return newFactor;
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 4**: Use your effect in the xaml:

```
<Setter Property="Effect">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ui:ColourAdjustEffect Saturation="0" Gamma="0.6" 
                               BrightnessAdjustment="-0.2" RedAdjustment="0.04" />
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

So while I didn't get my glow effect, I had enough parameters to play with that I could get a 'highlighting' visual cue, which was my real goal. Here's some of the things I was able to do with it:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try something like this (Note! This is not finished solutions just an idea):

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type Button}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border CornerRadius="10" BorderThickness="20">
                            <Border.BorderBrush>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0, 0.5" EndPoint="1, 0.5">
                                    <GradientStop Color="LightGreen" Offset="0.0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.15" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.BorderBrush>
                        </Border>
                        <Border CornerRadius="10" BorderThickness="20">
                            <Border.BorderBrush>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0, 0.5" EndPoint="1, 0.5">
                                    <GradientStop Color="LightGreen" Offset="1.0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.85" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.BorderBrush>
                        </Border>
                        <Border CornerRadius="10" BorderThickness="20">
                            <Border.BorderBrush>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5, 0" EndPoint="0.5, 1">
                                    <GradientStop Color="LightGreen" Offset="0.0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.15" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.BorderBrush>
                        </Border>
                        <Border CornerRadius="10" BorderThickness="20">
                            <Border.BorderBrush>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5 0" EndPoint="0.5, 1">
                                    <GradientStop Color="LightGreen" Offset="1.0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.85" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.BorderBrush>
                        </Border>
                        <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="5" Margin="18"></Border>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

We can make "glow" effect by playing with borders around some content in Grid. I feel it won't be so flexible of course as a InnerGlow BitmapEffect but anyway it is obsolete.

Comment: Points for effort man, it's a good idea. Kind of painful to come up with a new control template like this for each control, but a good workaround idea nonetheless.

Comment: Note that with gradient like that you will get some ugly intermediate gray colors. Better would be to use `#0000ff00` instead of `Transparent`